# GROUP EACH BY limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a huge table with 20,235,447,221 rows clocked in at 1.32 TB. I need to find the unique rows and count them so I use the GROUP EACH BY to accomplish that.

However, I get the Error: Resources exceeded during query execution error.

Is there anyway to execute the table without running out resources? If not, how do I find the ceiling of the number of rows a table can have for this to succeed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If a statistical approximation rather than an exact result is useful to you, COUNT(DISTINCT ...) is an option.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions

What is the GROUP EACH BY query text you're running?